# How to find vhd files in azure using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, vhd

I want to create VM from a disk in azure using python. So I need VHD file of the disk for this purpose.
How can I download or obtain the VHD file in azure using python. And on Azure portal, where are the VHD files listed?

I referred  a video where it was told to search under storage account->containers->vhds, but I did not find anything as such. 
 Then I found this :- **blob_service.get_blob_to_path**, but it also did not work for me.
Can anyone help me with this problem?
I want to obtain VHD file of the disk in azure using python.

Comment: Do you already have a VHD which you have uploaded to Azure storage? Or have you previously created a VM in Azure and now you want to recreate a new VM based on its disk? Or do you want to create a new VM based on the e.g. the Ubuntu 16.04 standard image?

Comment: @rasmusgude I read that VHD files are created for disks in blob storage, but when I go and check there, I don't see any vhd file. Is it right that VHD files are created for disks automatically? And if yes, how do I get them? and if No, how to create and find them.

Comment: Are you using managed disks? (this is the default when creating VMs via the Azure Portal). If so, then these disks will appear in the resource list as something like [vm_name]_1_3833086d58294a1baae9de2d08c6XXXX and will be of type 'Disk'.